# DAX calculating running sum of column power pivot

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have dataset as below,
I'm having trouble calculating the run total of the information in the "SATISSEZON" column,
I would be very grateful if you could help me regarding the issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adL9S.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtVYF.png)

```
CALCULATE([first value];FILTER(ALL('MerchDate');
'MerchDate'[Date]<=MAX(DATALAR[Date])))
```

EDİT
I got the result in the picture with the measurement

[image]

```
CALCULATE(SUM([DSSTOK])
;FILTER(ALL(MerchTarih);
    MerchTarih[HAREKETTARIHI]<=MAX(DATALAR[HAREKETTARIHI]))
    ;VALUES(UrunListesi[Pr_Detail])
    ;VALUES(Lokasyonlar[LOKASYONKODU])
    ;ALLSELECTED(SatisSezonu[SATISSEZONU]))
```

but when I look at the category basis, the stock values ​​of all seasons are the same.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Why do you want to hide 2022 values and show running total instead?

Comment: I can't get the point of measure, so, it's not clear what kind of result you are going to achive. I see values and it is possible to achieve, but the way to get this values can be wrong. So I need the logic. As I see you need to create a selective measure.

Comment: I understand 
I want to get the stock totals of a product at the end of summer and winter.
and I need to calculate it on a per category basis.
sample,
What is the summer stock of pants in the 28th week of the previous year?

Comment: please, add your clarification to the question? by editing.

Comment: I explained below

Comment: I see. I mean according to Stack overflow an answer should answer )

Comment: I see you fixed the issue, then Ok.

Comment: I edit my question as you requested